# Qt5 undefined reference to `QDeclarativeDebuggingEnabler::QDeclarativeDebuggingEnabler()'

Tags: c++, qt, qml, undefined-reference

Suddenly had this problem...

```
classitem.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/../../Qt/5.4/gcc_64/include/QtDeclarative/qdeclarativedebug.h:50: undefined reference to `QDeclarativeDebuggingEnabler::QDeclarativeDebuggingEnabler()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [MedJournal] Error 1
09:29:05: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
```

went as far as stripping the QObject class from the object, but still got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Remember there is a difference between QtQuick1 and QtQuick2 when enabling debugging:

QtQuick1

```
#include <QtDeclarative/qdeclarativedebug.h>
QDeclarativeDebuggingEnabler enabler;
```

QtQuick2

```
#include <QQmlDebuggingEnabler>
QQmlDebuggingEnabler enabler;
```

Since you are using Qt5.4 and QtQuick2 is arround since Qt5 I think, that might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that for some reason this line was causing all the trouble:

```
#include <QtDeclarative/QDeclarativeView>
```